# Is there a "rule" that figures "must" be at the top of a page, and tables at the bottom?

Tags: tables, floats

Today I had a discussion with my professor, who demands me to put all of my figures at the top of a page, and all tables at the bottom. None may be inline with the text.

He says that "this is the rule", although he cannot give me a source. Are there any arguments to back up his claim? If not, how can I convince him that this is bollocks?

Comment: This is not about TeX but rather about typesetting. Therefore it might appear better at [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ellen Swanson's "[Mathematics Into Type](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf)" says (p.70):

> **6.7.1 Graphics (figures)**
>
> [...]
>
> *Placement*. Graphics are placed preferably at the top or bottom of the page
> on which they are referred to in text, but definitely within the same section
> as the text reference.

"6.7.2 Tables" says nothing about placement, but since it's in the same section as "Graphics (figures)", it can be presumed that the same rule applies.

Chicago (14th edition) says (11.6, p.387, and calling figures "illustrations")

> An illustration should be placed as close as possible to the first text
> reference to it.  The illustration may precede the reference only if
> it is on the same page as the reference; otherwise it should follow.
> [...]

Regarding tables (15.20, p.497),

> *Tables, lists, and similar entities*.  Complicated tabular material, lists,
> and other entities that are not part of the text should be put
> in an appendix at the back of the book rather than in the footnotes.
> [...]

Clearly, this isn't directed toward scientific works.  (The 15th edition may differ,
but I don't have a copy handy.)

That said, David's comment is sound: if your professor is in a position to make the rules, his are the rules you should adhere to.

Answer (score 8):

If he is in a position to make the rules, that is the rule. If you want latex to follow them you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{tp}
\def\fps@table{bp}
\makeatother
```

(I kept `p` which allows float pages, you could get rid of that as well but the most likely all floats will go to the end of the document)

Comment: Thanks David. I am still trying to talk my way out of it, but if I do not succeed, I will use your solution.

Comment: +1 for: If he is in a position to make the rules, that is the rule

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any style guide that follows his recommendation. Of the major styles that I am aware of only Chicago and MLA allow for figures and tables to be in the text at all. Potentially, MLA even allows text to flow around "floats".

For [Chicago](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/02/)

> Position tables and figures after the paragraph in which they’re
>   described

For [MLA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/14/)

> Situate the table near the text to which it relates.
>
> MLA does not specify alignment requirements for figures; thus, these
>   images may be embedded as the reader sees fit. However, continue to
>   follow basic MLA Style formatting (e.g. one-inch margins).

For [APA](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-formatting.aspx#Tables)

> Place each table on a separate page at the end of your manuscript,
>   after the reference list.
>
> Place each figure on a separate page at the end of your manuscript,
>   after any tables (or after the reference list, if there are no
>   tables).

For [ASA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/583/01/)

> Each table or figure should be placed on a separate page at the end of
>   the manuscript, and should have a descriptive title that explains
>   enough that the reader can understand it without having to refer to
>   the text of the article.

For [AIP](http://www.aip.org/pubservs/style/4thed/AIP_Style_4thed.pdf)

> Type or print eacht able double spaced on a separate page after the references and before the figure captions.
>
> Place the figures themselves in sequence after the collected captions.

For [ACS](http://pubs.acs.org/isbn/9780841239999)

> Place formal tables after the references at the end of the text file, each on its
>   own page.
>
> Unless a publisher instructs otherwise, do not put the figures in the midst of
>   text; put them on separate pages at the end. Put one figure on each page, and label the page with the figure number only.

For [MHRA](http://www.mhra.org.uk/Publications/Books/StyleGuide/StyleGuideV3.pdf)

> They should not be embedded within the text but should be either placed at the end of the text or supplied as separate files.
>
> All illustrations should be supplied as separate files, not embedded within the text.

I don't have access to either Oxford or AMA. From what I can piece together from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Harts-Rules-Handbook-Reference/dp/0198610416) in Oxford tables and figures go at the end on separate pages.

Comment: some of these specs refer, explicitly or implicitly, to what is delivered to a publisher, not what is ultimately printed.  the original question applies to the "final product".  for that, the practice of publishers in the field should be examined.